# Rsync and repository configuration

Tags: networking, apt, cron, rsync

I'm setting up a local repository mirror, and I'm having some problems understanding the documentation (it's a bit out of date, from 2010).

I have a command line set up as part of a cron job that synchronizes my drive to the repository:

rsync -a --bwlimit=3072 --progress --delete rsync://archive.ubuntu.com /media/8TB/ubuntu

I have a link *that works* to the web server hosted on the same machine, from /var/www/html:

ln /media/8TB/ubuntu -s

The base directory of the repository browses from elsewhere on the network, because I get the proper directory when I point the browser to http://192.168.0.14/ubuntu.

I understand that Apache maps the URL to the drive through the softlink in /var/www/html.  That softlink is in a different location from the SxS, and leads to a different URL than the SxS.

More questions:What user should I set for the repository itself, and do I have to unset it when rsync runs as a cron job?  More specifically,

1)  Is this sufficient to serve as a local repository?  If so, what address should I give APT on each box to update locally (from the local repository)?

2)  What changes do I need to make to make this available from *outside* the network, other than the necessary router/network configuration?  I'm assuming if I port forward port 80 from my WAN IP to the repository server, it should presently be available from outside as http://[external IP]/ubuntu.  However, if I need to make conforming changes based on #1, above, this changes, correct?

3)  I would like the repository to be read-only until rsync runs, in which case rsync (some user?) needs write access long enough to complete the rsync process, and then it goes back to read-only.  How would I do this?

Comment: Providing a link to the documentation would have been handy. It may be perfectly up-to-date (the deb packaging system does not change very often as it's stable), but as you didn't provide the link we cannot check (& update it if necessary).

Comment: The documentation is here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror

Comment: That page was last updated on 2018-09-20 (not 2010), in fact has been amended many times since 2010.

Comment: The Apache setup is what concerns me, as ubuntudomain.mydomain is what I'm having problems understanding.  I *think* I understand the rest.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is this sufficient to serve as a local repository? If so, what address should I give APT on each box to update locally (from the local repository)?

Use your local IP address if it's static, otherwise you need to deploy DNS inside the network to specially update a dedicated FQDN for it.  Locally, IP is going to work best

> 2) What changes do I need to make to make this available from outside the network, other than the necessary router/network configuration? I'm assuming if I port forward port 80 from my WAN IP to the repository server, it should presently be available from outside as http://[external IP]/ubuntu. However, if I need to make conforming changes based on #1, above, this changes, correct?

Yes and no.  Unless you've got the mechanism to assign a domain to the repository server, or if your router is smart enough to handle NAT reflection, you may have a different 'local' vs. 'public' access route.  You can *attempt* to use `http://external_ip_here/` though from within your local network, it might work.

> 3) I would like the repository to be read-only until rsync runs, in which case rsync (some user?) needs write access long enough to complete the rsync process, and then it goes back to read-only. How would I do this?

Put this on a dedicated system and don't give anyone access to the system.  Further, on-system, don't give anyone write access EXCEPT the user that's doing the `rsync` job, and consider creating a *dedicated* system user for this without password.  This will be sufficient to control and lock down the permissions on the thing, and so only the rsync job/user will have access rights.

Comment: Answers:  
  
1) So for each computer, I should have the sources.list entry of:   
  
deb http://192.168.0.14/ubuntu/ main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: Let me pull up my RSync script I use for my mirrors so you can see what I do.  Then I will pull my Apache configs and share too.